# What is more important with a gaming dedicated server the processor or RAM?

Tags: dedicated-server, hardware, gameserver

I am just wondering what is more important for a dedicated server that will be running game servers (such as Minecraft, CS, Battlefield, etc) the processor or RAM? or does it change depending on the game?

Comment: While CPU and RAM are important, the network connection it more important than either of those, both low latency and decent bandwidth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It utterly depends on the serving application's useage profile - it could be CPU. memory, disk or network IO - these is no one answer to this question.

You just need to profile your application, see where it's 'hot' and fix that problem first - no short-cuts sorry.

Comment: thank you, that seems to be the most rounded answer. I was really hoping for a straight, This is it answer hahaha.

Comment: For some games, wouldn't you benefit from stellar GPU performance also? Or is it all the other extreme in this day and age: where the server just sends out instructions about how objects are moving about, and it's up to the client to actually render the scene?

Comment: Not as a game SERVER no as it's not the server doing the rendering.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the game and the player load. Minecraft, AFAIK, is very RAM-intensive while BF and CS needs a balance of both.

Answer (score 1):

For Minecraft, RAM.

As long as the server has a decent CPU, that will be fine. RAM and network connection can cause problems.